# Create a BIND Clause Programmatically in Jena

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena

How do I create a BIND clause and add it to an `ElementGroup`, For example, suppose I have a node and want to bind this to a variable. In SPARQL, such a statement would probably be represented as:

```
BIND ( IRI("http://www.example.com/x") as ?x)
```

suppose that I already have a node:

```
Node x = NodeFactory.createURI("http://www.example.com/x");
```

So, How can I create such a clause Programmatically and add it to an `ElementGroup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, it was not that difficult, except due to the lack of documentation,

Simple as:

```
ElementGroup elg = .... ;
Node mainSubjectNode = NodeFactory.createURI("http://www.example.com/x");
ElementBind x = new ElementBind(Var.alloc("asd"),NodeValue.makeNode(mainSubjectNode));
elg.addElement(x);
```

Comment: If this works for you, be sure to accept your answer.